# Angular material table with selection - master toggle should deselect first

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have modified (`masterToggle`) the original [Angular Material Table example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection) - [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lmgexmnarvra?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts) so that after some rows have been selected the master toggle should deselect all (instead of select all - similar to Gmail behavior).

It works but the master toggle checkbox in the header does not work as expected - after clicking it to deselect - the logic deselects the selected rows but the master toggle checkbox does not reflect the model value:

`[checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"`

I would expect the master toggle checkbox to not be ckecked if the expression evaluates to false (See the image bellow).

I guess that it has something to do with animations.

Modified example here: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmqg54?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.html)

```
masterToggle() {
    // if there is a selection then clear that selection
    if (this.isSomeSelected()) {
      this.selection.clear();
    } else {
      this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you are not updating the `this.selection.selected.length` while clicking the check box so it is not updating the length properly.

You need to explicitly change `mat-checkbox` state other wise it will keep toggling itself so i have used template ref to `mat-checkbox` to unchecked

`isSomeSelected()` method not executing while you clicking `mat-cell` in order to check `masterToggle()` if condition properly you have to trigger this method while clicking `mat-checkbox` check my solution I have added this function inside change event so that it will work properly

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null;isSomeSelected()"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
```

I have modified your code check this :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmqg54-7rjmaj

Comment: > *Currently you are not updating the this.selection.selected.length while clicking the check box*

I have added the `selection.selected.length` as debug to html - it is updating correctly.

Your solution is working but I do not understand why it is required to manually checking the checkbox using the template reference.

Comment: Yes, sure your solution using the template reference is working But I do not still understand what's wrong with the `selection.selected.count` and why the checkbox is checked, even if the expression `[checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"` **evaluates to false** - visible in HTML as debug - that it is false. Please see the my original StackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmqg54?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.html) as I added some debug info to html, also I have updated the image in question.

Comment: Sorry bro, your solution still needs the template reference to manually uncheck the checkbox to work. Anyway thanks for your effort :)

`isSomeSelected()` is updating correctly - see updated debug value here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmqg54?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177100/discussion-between-felix-and-chellappan).

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue, my solution was to change the `checked` state of the master toggle so that it's true when any item is selected, instead of just when all items are selected ([StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmqg54-mqljmj))

```
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
```

When a proper subset of the items is selected `indeterminate` will be true, so the check is not actually shown. However, as mentioned by @Chellappan the checkbox toggles the check state with every click (see [source](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/4002140363ab364e5abc95dae7013aa73439c112/src/material/checkbox/checkbox.ts#L388)), thus the checkbox will transition into the unchecked state with the next click, as desired.

```
  /**
   * Event handler for checkbox input element.
   * Toggles checked state if element is not disabled.
   * Do not toggle on (change) event since IE doesn't fire change event when
   *   indeterminate checkbox is clicked.
   * @param event
   */
  _onInputClick(event: Event) {
    [...]
    this._transitionCheckState(
          this._checked ? TransitionCheckState.Checked : TransitionCheckState.Unchecked);
    [...]
  }
```

Unfortunately this is coupling the code to what is arguably an implementation detail. Another potential workaround is to return `false` from the checkbox's click handler to prevent the Angular click handler from evaluating, however in my testing keyboard interaction on the checkbox does not trigger the checkbox's click handler, but does trigger the Angular one, so the bug will persist.

A true, but involved, solution would be set [`MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION`](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview#click-action-config) to `noop` and implement a custom click action

Answer (score 0):

```
public dataSourceNew
public selection=new SelectionModel<leadsPendingUser>(true, []);

abc(){
     //after your api call 
     if(res.success==true){
        const ELEMENT_DATA: leadsPendingUser[]=this.PartnerManagementModel.data
        this.dataSourceNew = new MatTableDataSource<leadsPendingUser>(ELEMENT_DATA);

        //** the only change you need to do is below line **//
        this.selection = new SelectionModel<leadsPendingUser>(true, []);

        this.dataSourceNew.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSourceNew.sort = this.sort;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please add some text to elaborate on your answer. Just posting code is generally not accepted on StackOverflow.